# Cordova adding plugin fails

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a phonegap app and trying to install a clipboard manager plugin as

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-clipboard-x
```

The output is:

```
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-clipboard-x" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-clipboard-x" for browser
Installing "cordova-plugin-clipboard-x" for ios
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-clipboard-x':Error
    at Object.parseProjectFile [as parse] (/Users/vskumar/PhoneGap/InstaSmart/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/projectFile.js:51:15)
    at Api.addPlugin (/Users/vskumar/PhoneGap/InstaSmart/platforms/ios/cordova/Api.js:224:33)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:611:6)
    at /usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:407:28
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
Error: Could not find *-Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
```

I have no idea how to fix it. There is indeed a config.xml file in my root folder.

Comment: any one on this plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly update your node and cordova version and then create the project.
And then add the

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-clipboard-x
```

It will works.